# Select AVG of rows using Query Builder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

- I want to select the average of columns 'note' from a table
  'noteparagraphe' where 
      the id_paragraphe is a parameter ($ref), I tried this query but I'm getting nothing back !

  ```
     $query=$this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
     ->createQuery('Select avg(n.note) from ParagrapheBundle:NoteParagraphe n 
     WHERE n.id_paragraphe = :idModele');

     $query->setParameter('idModele', $ref);
     $query->execute();
     $avgNote = $query->getResult();
  ```

the SQL is : SELECT AVG(note) from note_paragraphe WHERE id_paragraphe=?

Answer (score 0):

Use Query builder:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ParagrapheBundle:NoteParagraphe');

$avgNote = $query->createQueryBuilder('n')
    ->select('avg(n.note)')
    ->where('n.id_paragraphe = :idModele')
    ->setParameter('idModele', $ref);
    ->getQuery();
```

See if that works - I haven't tried it, but I think it should work.